# IIS Redirect with Arguments

Tags: iis

I know you can do page redirects with IIS so if someone hits example.com it sends the user to www.example.com but is there a way to do something to make it possible to redirect with the values from example.com/index.aspx?p=1 to www.example.com/index.aspx?p=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS 7 or above you can use URL Rewrite ( http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite ) for that very easily, it includes a template that will actually do the "canonical host name" for you.